# two php field inside html

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $year=$_POST["year"];
        ?>
        <div id="wrap">
            <?php
                echo "<h3>".$year."</h3>";
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that I assign the content of `$_POST` to the variable `$year` in the first PHP code block. Can I use `$year` in the second php code block without directly using the `$_POST` variable again?

Comment: Where is the $_POST['year'] coming from?. Can you post your code.

Comment: @Mike from the previous page.

Comment: Is the code not working? If so, do you get any errors?

Comment: I've edited the question so it is more readable as I believe this is what you were actually asking.

Comment: @Mike Thank you, Mike. That's what I want to asking. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Once you have assigned a variable and it is in scope you can use it again and again, unless you re-assign it, or unassign it.

Comment: It would be better to escape your $year data to prevent malicios contents to be written to page

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
$year=$_POST["year"];
```

here your $_POST variable is assigned to another variable $year (it can be given a totally different name, maybe something more readable). It automatically becomes a global variable and you can use it in the page anywhere after assigning.

[Here you can learn more about PHP variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: thanks for incorporating my edits. It makes it clearer

Comment: @Mike thanks for improving my answer. I'am not that good in English as it's not my native language. any help from people like you always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you are assigning `$_POST['year']` to the `$year variable`.

```
$year=$_POST["year"];
```

So `$year` will hold the `$_POST['year']` value. So you can use `$year` after assigning.